# Computing stats on generators in single pass. Python

Tags: python, statistics, generator

When working with generators you can only pull out items on a single pass. An alternative is to load the generator into an list and do multiple passes but this involves a hit on performance and memory allocation.

Can anyone think of a better way of computing the following metrics from a generator in a single pass. Ideally the code computes the count, sum, average, sd, max, min and any other stats you can think of.

*UPDATE*

Initial horrid code in this gist.
See the gist here: https://gist.github.com/3038746

Using the great suggestions from @larsmans here is the final solution I went with. Using the named tuple really helped.

```
import random
from math import sqrt
from collections import namedtuple

def stat(gen):
    """Returns the namedtuple Stat as below."""
    Stat = namedtuple('Stat', 'total, sum, avg, sd, max, min')
    it = iter(gen)

    x0 = next(it)
    mx = mn = s = x0
    s2 = x0*x0
    n = 1

    for x in it:
        mx = max(mx, x)
        mn = min(mn, x)
        s += x
        s2 += x*x
        n += 1

    return Stat(n, s, s/n, sqrt(s2/n - s*s/n/n), mx, mn)

def random_int_list(size=100, start=0, end=1000):
    return (random.randrange(start,end,1) for x in xrange(size))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = stat(random_int_list())
    print r  #Stat(total=100, sum=56295, avg=562, sd=294.82537204250247, max=994, min=10)
```

Comment: `stat.n    += 1.0` Thousands of dead mathematicians are rolling in their graves...

Comment: Use numpy. It has all the built-in features you need and it is faster than python loops.

Comment: Lol @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams any other way you could do this with a generator?

Comment: I'm not sure if numpy object creation would actually be faster than this single pass @eumiro but it's worth a try

Comment: What's the point of the stat function? You can simply inline the function and the LC as a loop. That saves you the list you throw away for `x`

Comment: Before I wanted to see the evolution of the stats as they where generated but I totally agree x isn't needed.

Comment: Remember about `itertools.tee`

Comment: @Kos how can itertools.tee be used in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def statistics(it):
    """Returns number of elements, sum, max, min"""

    it = iter(it)

    x0 = next(it)
    maximum = minimum = total = x0
    n = 1

    for x in it:
        maximum = max(maximum, x)
        minimum = min(minimum, x)
        total += x
        n += 1

    return n, total, maximum, minimum
```

Add other statistics as you please. Consider using a `namedtuple` when the number of statistics to compute grows large.

If you want to get really fancy, you can build an OO hierarchy of statistics collectors (untested):

```
class Summer(object):
    def __init__(self, x0=0):
        self.value = x0

    def add(self, x):
        self.value += x

class SquareSummer(Summer):
    def add(self, x):
        super(SquareSummer, self).add(x ** 2)

class Maxer(object):
    def __init__(self, x0):
        self.value = x0

    def add(self, x):
        self.value = max(self.value, x)

# example usage: collect([Maxer, Summer], iterable)
def collect(collectors, it):
    it = iter(it)

    x0 = next(it)
    collectors = [c(x0) for c in collectors]

    for x in it:
        for c in collectors:
            c.add(x)

    return [c.value for c in collectors]
```

Comment: This is great @larsmans but why the need for it = iter(it) is this defensive type checking?

Comment: @MattAlcock: it's needed to get the function to work on iterables as well as iterators. E.g., `next([1])` raises a `TypeError`.